# Super key and auto hide the taskbar noy working

Tags: shortcut-keys, 16.10, appearance

I have two problems:

1.When i tried to press th win key/super key in my hp pavillion laptop, the dash did not come up.
2.When i clicked on "Auto-hide the Launcher" and revealed location to the left side, the launcher did not reveal when moving the pointer to the defined hot spot.

Comment: One question at a time please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your 2 question increase Reveal Sensitivity

[image]